# How to resolve a 502 Bad Gateway error on nginx when running a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, kubernetes

I have set up a Kubernetes cluster with some back-end microservices and they all work fine with nginx. However, I cannot access my angular front end because it gives me a 502 error.

The Dockerfile for my angular app (I tried many different implementations and this is the most recent one):

```
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run ng build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder app/dist/ride-sharing /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The yaml file for my Kubernetes deployment & service for the angular app:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontendx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontendx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontendx
          image: akeedm/frontendx

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontendx
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: frontendx
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4200
      targetPort: 4200
```

The yaml file for my ingress configuration (the last route is the problem):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'

spec:
  rules:
    - host: rides.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /users/create
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: enduser-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 4000
          - path: /users
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: query-srv
                port:
                  number: 5200
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: query-srv
                port:
                  number: 5200
          - path: /users/?(.*)/adverts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: advert-srv
                port:
                  number: 4100
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 4200
```

After applying the yaml files and deploying the kubernetes cluster I can connect to all the services properly except for the angular app. When I try to connect to https://rides.com I get the error 502 Bad Gateway. When I try to view the logs at */var/log/nginx*, both the access.log and error.log files are empty.

Below is the terminal for my running pod for the angular app as it starts. There are no new entries when I get the 502 error.

> /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will
> attempt to perform configuration
>
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in
> /docker-entrypoint.d/
>
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching
> /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
>
> 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
>
> 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
>
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching
> /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
>
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching
> /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
>
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up

Comment: Have you tried running your FE container separately e.g. in docker to see if it works? To understand where the issue is. Also please run `kubectl describe ingress ingress-srv` and post it here.